# "Skipping incompatible library" when building Qt project with libtiff

Tags: c++, qt, libtiff

Qt's standard image library does not support multi-layer and multi-channel TIFF files, so I wanted to use libtiff for that and downloaded it from http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/

I built it with nmake (nmake /f makefile.vc), linked to the library in Qt and tried to build the project afterwards, but I'm getting the following error messages.

[image]

The build command is

```
C:\Qt\5.12.3\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe C:\Sync\Programmierung\Qt\MAIAS2Database\MAIAS2Database.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler" && C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make.exe qmake_all
```

and I have checked the header and library files. They are in the same folder and got included in the project with

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/libtiff/ -llibtiff

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/lib/libtiff
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/lib/libtiff
```

I am pretty sure I compiled the libtiff library wrong or have to do some extra steps, but I can't figure it out. I'm using Qt on Windows 10 and would love to get this to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `makefile.vc` -- Was that library built with Visual C++?  If so, then you need to build your application with the Visual C++ compiler toolset.

Comment: I used the Visual Studio Developer Console and just entered the command "nmake /f makefile.vc" without any further configuration. Would I be able to somehow make this work with Qt on Windows? What would I have to use to build the library instead of nmake?

Comment: According to what you indicate libtiff has been compiled using VS (nmake) and you want to use it with mingw, mmm, and that cannot be done.

Comment: `C:\Qt\5.12.3\mingw73_64` -- Then you're using mingw to build your application?  That isn't going to work.  The mingw uses `g++` as the compiler toolset.

Comment: If you want to compile using mingw then you should use "mingw32-make"(or "mingw64-make") instead of nmake

Comment: Also you mention "Qt on Windows".  QT is not a compiler -- it is configured to use a compiler that is installed on your system.  Thus it can launch different compiler toolsets, depending on the configuration.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did try that, but when I used "mingw32-make" with any of the makefiles (Makefile.in is probably the correct one) it just told me there was "Nothing to be done".

Comment: TBH, sometimes it is just plain easier to add the libtiff source to your application and not need to build any external libraries, and just compile it with your app.  It is about 20 or so `.c` files (from what I remember).

Comment: @Endauriel please read the readme: `./configure` `make` `make install`

Comment: @eyllanesc Isn't that for Linux? Windows will find neither of those commands.

Comment: another solution is create a .pri

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've tried your solution, but some of the files seem to contain syntax errors that make compiling them impossible.

Comment: What were the errors?  Probably you need to adjust the `tiffconf.h` and/or `tiff_config.h` files to fit your compiler.  Other than that, the files are generic `.C` files.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "Unknown type name "TIFF_INT8_T" and a bunch of others in "tiff.h", the same in "tiffiop.h" and other files.

Comment: ok.  I have an old copy of libtiff, and `TIFF_INT8_T` is defined in tiffconf.h as `signed char`.  You need to get a good source code browser to figure out these errors, TBH.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got it down to a bunch of Pragma Warnings, but 3 errors still remain, all 3 in "tiff.h".

C:\Sync\Programmierung\Qt\MAIAS2Database\libtiff\tiff.h:75: Error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int64'

C:\Sync\Programmierung\Qt\MAIAS2Database\libtiff\tiff.h:76: Error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'uint64'

C:\Sync\Programmierung\Qt\MAIAS2Database\libtiff\tiff.h:105: Error: unknown type name 'uint64'

Comment: Make sure that `tiffconf.h` is defining `TIFF_UINT64_T` for the build.

Comment: That file contains #define TIFF_UINT64_T unsigned __int64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211984/discussion-between-paulmckenzie-and-endauriel).